# Remove specific resize handler jQuery

Tags: jquery, resize

I have a resizable container div. Inside that div there's another resizable div.
If I destroy the resize handler of the container div, the inner div's resize handler is destroyed as well. Like this:

`$(".container").resizable("destroy");`

Is there a way to destroy resize handler of the container but keep the resize handler on the div inside the container?

Comment: I think you can only do this by editing the jQuery UI source.. actually it looks like a bug for me because you can't even add the resize handler to the inner div again when removing it by just removing the resize handler of the outer div [check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/D92vA/) I would say report it [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/report/10?P=resizable) and wait for the next version of jQuery UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does appear to be a bug in the jQuery UI source. The "destroy" call on the parent container is removing the ui-resizable-handle from the target container object and all contained elements.

The root of the problem is in the destroy function in jquery.ui.resizable.js on line 198 (as of JQuery UI v1.8.20).

Notice that it is calling:

```
.find('.ui-resizable-handle').remove();
```

This should be changed instead to:

```
.children('.ui-resizable-handle').remove();
```

Changing this call will prevent the ui-resizable-handle from being removed from your inner div.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I reported the issue. Hopefully it'll be fixed for you soon. Here is a reference to the bug report: [link](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8344)